# How do I organize webforms in admin panel

Tags: webforms

I want to customize the Webforms Admin view. 
Place all the related webforms in a groups and control who can access the groups.

For example I have many departments. I create a group to each department and allow group members to access  the webforms and not other departments.

Can anybody direct me how to achieve this?

Comment: I just need to know  how do I proceed or achieve it.I'm still blank and don't know where do I start  from to achieve this. Any useful tips is helpful

Answer (score 1):

How many Webforms do you have? I have worked on huge sites, and I have never had enough forms to even fill one page.

As for filtering, you can already go to `/admin/content` and filter by Content type = webform, or just go to `/admin/content/webform`.

If you need even more control over filtering, then you need to create a custom administrative View. With that, you can add filters for whatever you need, and pagination.

Group level access permissions are more difficult, but not impossible. Start here: https://www.drupal.org/project/permissions_per_webform. If that is not what you need, then look at the many other  modules available for controlling access/permissions.

Last, I think your question was voted down because of several things. First, it is not helpful to make general negative comments like "not well organized". Second, this is not the place to make demands for new features. Third, is the fact that you don't seem to have done even basic searches for the functionality you need.

Last, is your presumption that webforms need to be changed to suit your use-case. Drupal is very powerful because it is modular. Just because you need a certain set of features does not mean that those very specific features would be helpful to anyone else. You should be able to build the functionality you need, but the key word here is "build". Drupal gives you the power to add a GPS to a lawnmower, but that doesn't mean you can demand that every lawnmower sold has a GPS.

Comment: I need some information to start modifying the administrative View.Thank you very much. I am trying to customize the Administrative view. Webforms keeps growing from a few hundreds to thousands so I am thinking alternative way to show webforms instead of just table

Comment: This is really not the correct place for such a complex question. You really should try the forms on the Drupal site: https://www.drupal.org/forum/22

Comment: Again, I need to ask. How in the world are you ending up with thousands of webforms? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I have changed my comments. And I will improve the way I post next time.